# How could I avoid that the URL changes the brackets into ASCII code?

Tags: url, asp.net-web-api, ascii

I am building a WebAPI with Entity Framework.
Once of the Api addresses is: /api/organizations/{id}, where {id} is a parameter that receive the id of the organization.

If I run the API in Postman tool, like: http://localhost:50895/api/organizations/2, I get all the data of the organization 2.

Back to the front-end, I get the right url: http://localhost:50895/api/organizations/2 but a page without data. And the console shows not error, but the message:

```
**GET http://localhost:50895/api/organizations/%7Bid%7D 204 No Content**
```

Meaning, I think, that the brackets "{" and "}" were changed by their ASCII code **%7B** and **%7D** which is not the correct URl and it gets an empty result.

How could I avoid that the URL changes the brackets into ASCII code?

**EDIT**

I am using angular in the front end:
clicking in the name of the organization I pass the id to the controller and it pass it through to the back-end controller:

```
<a ui-sref="organization({Id: organization.id})">{{ organization.organizationName }}</a>
```

**EDIT 2**
the DOM looks like this [image: Headers Tab]
[image]

Comment: That request was for the literal `.../organizations/{id}` - there was no replacement of the `id` value with `2`. How are you doing the request manually?

Comment: I am just using a link n the front end that changes dynamically the id. I added it to the question

Comment: What does the DOM look like before you click on the link?

Comment: I added the DOm's views

Comment: That's not the DOM, that's the Request/Response.